# How to point one domain to deep page of another domain with apache or htaccess

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, redirect

I have two domains (a.com and b.com) and a.com is running on my apache server.  I want web browsers that try to visit b.com to end up at a.com/?b (transparently, no redirect, and no second virtual host if possible).

I see that within the virtual host config i can rewrite [(as shown here)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) but it's not clear and there are no examples.

Can someone propose the simplest way to solve this, ideally without another virtual host?

---

UPDATE:

I'm trying to solve it something like this.  I think I'm close but a bit lost:

```
<virtualhost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80>
        ServerName   a.com
        ServerAlias  b.com
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\b\.com
        RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1a.com/?b [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Somebody has to set up a virtual host for this, whether you or someone else.

Comment: Is it possible to share the same virtual host as a.com ?  And if so, how would I direct to the right page?

Comment: Yes, but it makes your setup much more complicated. Just make a new virtual host. It's simple, easy and fast.

Comment: Would I need to redirect (eg 301) if I use a new virtual host? I want this to be transparent

Answer (score 0):

You could use *Reverse HTTP proxy* configuration on your apache server. 
[Check this out](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html)

Your http server will be essentially serving content of another server.
e.g.:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://a.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://a.com:8080/
    ServerName b.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: And it will need a virtualhost, just what the OP doesn't want.

Comment: There is nothing bad with virtualhost, in this case it will not redirect the client, your webserver will essentially be able to serve clients requests in the following fashion. Cllient --> Your server A (Server A connects to server B for content) --> ServerB, Server B responds to server A, then the content is provided to the client by Server A. So in the headers clients will see only ServerA's IP.